# How do you set the size of an array that is exposed in Blueprint from within Blueprint?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Is there a way to expose an array of undetermined size to the blueprint editor so that the level/game designer can adjust the size of the array?

In my example, I want an array of gunshot sound effects.

In my header file I have this:

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
USoundBase* MuzzleSound[5];
```

... but I don't know how to do it without having to already know the size.

Over in BP I want some way to be able to adjust the size to add even more if desired:
[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [TArray](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TArray/). TArrays are the default array the editor uses within blueprints.

```
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere)
    TArray<USoundBase*> MuzzleSound;
```